# vimeo/YouTube iframe video wheel event

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I'm doing a Firefox addon to intercept wheel mouse events over an embedded iframe video of Youtube or Vimeo.
I got it working over normal YT/vimeo pages (attaching the listener to the window and then looking at event.target to identify the video), the problem is with the < iframe> tag: it doesn't intercept the "wheel" event (while for example "mouseover" works).

i.e. there is a similar HTML code in a page:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/89055435/fallback?noscript" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This works:

```
iframes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", func, false);
```

For "wheel" I do the similar:

```
iframes[i].addEventListener("wheel", myFunc, false);
or
iframes[i].contentWindow.addEventListener("wheel", myFunc, false);
```

No result. I tried also capturing instead of bubbling: nothing.

I tried also this:

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", myFunc, false);
```

This works over every obj of the page, but nothing over the iframe itself.
I made also a setTimeout with the listener, to see if the iframe was not fully loaded: nothing changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/chtNP/121/

So, what should I do to have my wheel event when I'm over an iframe with a video inside it or how to get all wheels from the window including those over the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is my solution:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener('wheel', event => 
    iframe.dispatchEvent(new WheelEvent('wheel', event))
);
```

this will forward every `wheel`-event on the iframes document to the `iframe` element in the parent document.

Notes:

- it is not possible to 'recicle' the event, it needs to be cloned
- the WheelEvent constructor copies many, but not all of the original `event`s properties
- the cloned event is not `isTrusted`
- the event forwarding is attached to the iframes **document**. It will only work as long as the document doesn't change. So you should run the above code once the final document is loaded
- accessing the iframes document may get you in cross-domain-trouble